# SQL Server 2012 - where is Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I recently downloaded and installed the [RC0 of SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28145).

I followed the installation process as usual, however - I can't seem to find SQL Server Management Studio (ssms.exe).

Where can it be found?

Comment: Denali comes with "SQL Server Data Tools" (SSDT). It looks like Visual Studio

Answer (score 5):

I got it installed the other night and it was under Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (I think was the full name). Same folder structure as SQL Server 2008 R2.

You can also just go to Start > Run, and type in `ssms.exe`.

If neither of these work you might want to just search your system drive for the exe to see if it actually got installed. You may not have checked the box for management tools depending on how you walked through the wizard.